# I am Having issue with google Spreadsheet, how can I convert the 6.50min to 6.30 min

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvCQO.png)

In this I am not able to convert the time from 6.50 to 6.30 can anyone help. I have used this formula =SUM(D10-C10)*24 pls help

Please click the above link for image.

Comment: I don't recommend using h.mm if you want to have hours and minutes. The `.` instead of `:` is a good indicator of when you have minutes and when you have part of an hour. Same thing for GPS coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calculating the total number of hours it looks like it is just right to show 6.5 hours since you are displaying it in a decimal float format.

Unless you want to display it as hours & minutes (HH:MM) format you can do so just by `=SUM(D10-C10)`, then manually set the formatting of the cell to HH:MM by highlighting the cell then going to Format tab > Number > Custom date and time > Scroll down and select the time format which is in your case you want it to be in HH:MM

[image]

HOUR:MINUTE

[image]

It will show as 6:30, as shown in below screenshot:
[image]

or if you really want it to be displayed in decimal float format you can also manually do so in the Format tab > Number > **Custom number format** > In the box you can just type `"h"."mm"`. [image]

- Refer to this link for more details on Date and Number Formats: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to not use h.mm if you want to have "numeric" hours. You will never be sure how many minutes you have.

On the contrary, when you see 6.10 you will be able to know that you have 6 hours and 6 minutes (1/10th of an hour), and when you see 6:30 you will be able to know that you have 10 minutes.

Comment: This is a very interesting insight and great advice on how to manage the minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that can also be used

```js
=TEXT(D10-C10,"h.mm")
```

I used the example image to create my own sheet and run some test based on the formatting nature of the Google Sheets. It gives me the exact 6.30 that you need, without the need of making too many changes on the formats.

You can review it over my testing [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-wgf4MknvxsmNVmF7zG-AH4VYdIx3LyjdCYxfrWTNEE/edit#gid=0)